# If Two Independent Geometric Random Variables are equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be independent geometric random variables with parameters $p_2$ and $p_2$ , respectively.
Find $P (W_1 = W_ 2 )$.

To me this question seems unsolvable. I think we can assume $W_1=p_1$ and $W_2=P_2$. Also, I think we can assume that $W_1+W_2=1$. However it mentions that they are geometric random variables, which we have not learned in the class. So, I am guessing that it is very closely related to Poisson distribution.

For context, the section this comes from was about Poisson distribution. 
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{(n-k)}\rightarrow \frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{k}}{k!}$$ 
$$\text{as  }n\rightarrow \infty \text{ and } p\rightarrow 0 \text{ with } np=\mu$$

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the answer (though I haven't checked closely), but I'm a little concerned that you think a random variable (e.g., $W_1$ or $W_2$) should be equal to a parameter of its distribution (e.g., $p_1$ or $p_2$), or that you have some reason to think that $W_1+W_2 = 1$, or even that $p_1+p_2 = 1$.  But perhaps you're just writing about this in a strange way.  Can you clarify why you think the above can be assumed, as you claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A geometric random variable with parameter $p$ has probability mass function
$$
p(k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p,\quad k=1,2,\ldots.
$$
So if $W_1\sim\mathrm{Geo}(p_1)$ and $W_2\sim\mathrm{Geo}(p_2)$ are independent, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(W_1=W_2) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\{W_1=W_2, W_1=k\} \right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(W_1=W_2,W_1=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(W_1=k,W_2=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(W_1=k)\mathbb P(W_2=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p_1)^{k-1}p_1(1-p_2)^{k-1}p_2\\
&= p_1p_2\sum_{k=0}^\infty ((1-p_1)(1-p_2))^k\\
&= \frac{p_1p_2}{1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}.
\end{align}

Comment: I am confused on how you perform your last step. How do you remove the summation?

Comment: @Squanchy For $x\in\mathbb R$ with $|x|<1$, it is well-known that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac 1{1-x}$ (geometric series).